# How to get maximum number of rows in GogleSheet sheet in app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row

What kind of formula should I use to get the maximum number of rows of an active sheet in GogleSheet in app script? (of a specific column)
Could anyone assist?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. What does `get the maximum number of rows of an active sheet` mean?

Comment: it means the total number of rows that are fulfilled e.g. if you have data in cell A1, A2, A3 the total number of rows are 3

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, is this answer useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, I flagged it as a duplicate question.